# Installation of python, pip from administrator account not playing well with users

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm

I am having a heck of a time installing an IDE, python and pip to play well across user accounts.

I have started a new job, where I am allowed to work on school/programming stuff at work. I've even been given the go-ahead to install everything I need on my work computer (two nice big monitors!).

I have also been given administrative login, as I can't install anything on my regular account.

So, I log in to the admin account and followed the documentation on how to install Python and Pip for all users:

1. Check option for install for all uses
2. Check Add Python 3.8 to path
3. Select Customize installation
4. Again select Install for all users
5. Ensure the installation path is not in a user directory but rather in C:/Programs/Python...
6. Install PyCharm IDE

Great. Done. I reboot my machine and login to my humble user account and clone a project from GitHub.

Ok, so I want to add a package using pip... First thing I notice is that `pip install <package>` doesn't work at all. I get a type error.

Next, I try `py pip install <package>` and that gets things going, but of course fails after downloading the package. I don't have access to install it.

So I read the solution is to use `py pip install <package> --user`, which proceeds to tell me that installation is complete and successful with one warning:

```
WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\WNeill\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I find this interesting, since that's not where I installed Python. Also I find it interesting, because I had the installer add Python to the PATH. I verify my python installation is indeed in my machine's "Program Files" and satisfied that it is, I look up the f2py.script and find that it is part of the package I just tried to install.

A little wierded out, I type my `import` statement. Sure enough. No dice. "no module named numpy"

At this point, I'm a bit tired of running back and forth between two different user accounts repeatedly installing things and uninstalling them. I've been at it for about 6 hours. **Is there a way to make python, my IDE and pip all play nicely together or should I just go back to bringing my personal laptop to work and forget my dreams of coding on one big screen with documentation up on the other?**

**Edit 1**: I don't think this matters, but I'm no expert. I'm doing all of this from the PyCharm native terminal which is running Git Bash.

**Edit 2**: I decided to check my environment variables on my user account (even though they were added to the PATH variable from the admin account. The PATH variable was not set, so I added the the `python38` path and he `python38/Scripts`. Now I am getting a whole new set of errors which, among other things in a two page error report, is telling me that I have to download Microsoft Visual C++. Is this for real?

**Edit 3**: I have also tried  `pip install --upgrade setuptools` at another user's suggestion. This too fails miserably with error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==19.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 78, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 225, in main
    session = self._build_session(
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 87, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\download.py", line 344, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\download.py", line 134, in user_agent
    setuptools_version = get_installed_version("setuptools")
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 902, in get_installed_version
    working_set = pkg_resources.WorkingSet()
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 565, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 621, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1886, in find_eggs_in_zip
    if metadata.has_metadata('PKG-INFO'):
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1405, in has_metadata
    return self.egg_info and self._has(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1760, in _has
    return zip_path in self.zipinfo or zip_path in self._index()
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1637, in zipinfo
    return self._zip_manifests.load(self.loader.archive)
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\data-science-at-home\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1594, in load
    mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\WNeill\\PycharmProjects\\data-science-at-home\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg'
```